# Add Elementor Template to Second Query

Tags: wordpress, templates, elementor

I'm getting a second array of posts using get_posts, and adding it to the main query and it displays fine (add_adverts_to_loop)... and I can't seem to load the elementor loop template for the this query. I've tried also with query_posts, and WP_Query and could not get it right. I'd like to ask if it's possible to do it something like the two ways shown?

Thank you.

The queries work fine, but the template does not get added.

`add_filter( 'the_posts', 'add_adverts_to_loop', 10, 2 );
function add_adverts_to_loop( $posts, $query ) {

```
if ( is_admin() ) { return $posts;  }
if ( ! is_main_query() ) { return $posts; }

$freq = 5;

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'advert',
);

$recipes = get_posts( $args );
if ( $recipes ) {

    $insert = -1;

$template_id = 788; // template ID elementor
$elementor_instance = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
$elementor_instance->frontend->register_styles();
$elementor_instance->frontend->enqueue_styles();

    foreach ( $recipes as $recipe ) {

        $querr = $elementor_instance->frontend->get_builder_content_for_display($template_id); // not working

        $insert = $insert + ( $freq + 1 );
        array_splice( $posts, $insert, 0, array( $recipe ) );
    }
wp_reset_query();
}
return $posts;
```

}

add_filter( 'posts_results', 'my_posts_results_filter' );
function my_posts_results_filter( $posts ) {

```
if ( is_admin() ) { return $posts;  }
if ( ! is_main_query() ) { return $posts; }

$filtered_posts = array();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type=='advert' ) {
        $template_id = 788; // template ID elementor
        $elementor_instance = \Elementor\Plugin::instance();
        $elementor_instance->frontend->register_styles();
        $elementor_instance->frontend->enqueue_styles();

        $filtered_posts[] = \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->frontend->get_builder_content_for_display($template_id);
    } else {
    $filtered_posts[] = $post;
    }
}
return $filtered_posts;
```

}`